# Unchecked cast behavior with and without assignment to variable

Tags: java, generics, unchecked-exception

Why first line in main does not throw ClassCastException while the second does?

```
import java.util.function.Function;

class Scratch {

    static <T> T getSomething(Function<Integer, T> fun) {
        return (T) fun;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scratch.<String>getSomething(x -> "hello");
        String something = Scratch.<String>getSomething(x -> "hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't answer the question, but you're apparently trying to cast a Function<Integer,String> to String, which is unlikely to work. There needs to be a call to fun.apply in there somewhere.

Comment: Because you use the result in the second case, but not in the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is because you don't use the result of the method in the first case, but you do in the second.

A cast is an *expression*, but it's not a `StatementExpression`. This means that you can't write this:

```
(String) somethingReturningAString();
```

but you can write:

```
String aString = (String) somethingReturningAString();
```

At compile time, the compiler inserts `checkcast` instructions where it needs to, and where it can:

- It can't insert a cast for the first case, so no checking takes place.
- It can (and has to) insert a cast in the second case, in order to ensure that it's assigning something that's actually a `String` to a `String` variable. As such, it checks the cast, and that fails.

---

It's worth noting that there are some perhaps unexpected cases where a cast isn't *strictly* necessary, but is inserted. For example:

```
Scratch.<String>getSomething(x -> "hello").toString();
```

would fail with a `ClassCastException`, since it would be transformed to:

```
((String) Scratch.getSomething(x -> "hello")).toString();
```

even though `Object` has a `toString()` method, and so it could invoke that without a cast.

Answer (score 1):

Generics are only a compile time check (read about [type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens)). So at runtime your `getSomething()` method looks similar to this:

```
static Object getSomething(Function fun) {
    return fun;
}
```

Now you see clearly that the first line will never throw an exception

```
Scratch.getSomething(x -> "hello");
```

because `Function` **is** an `Object` and thus can be returned without a problem.

The second line however *will* throw one, because it will look similar to this:

```
String something = (String) Scratch.getSomething(x -> "hello");
```

A `Function` is still an `Object` so it can be returned from the method, but it is not a `String` and thus, you get your `ClassCastException`.

The code compiles fine, because you instruct the compiler that you know what you're doing. You will get an `Unchecked cast` warning though on this line:

```
 return (T) fun;
```

This warning should be an indicator from the compiler to you, the programmer, that it (the compiler) can't be sure that that cast will succeed.